# Need sample message for HL7 V2.7

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

I am looking for sample Hl7 V2.7 mesage for learning purpose, have not found in internet. Could some one please give one some sample message.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Here is a sample HL7 message:

```
MSH|^~\&||.|||199908180016||ADT^A04|ADT.1.1698593|P|2.7
PID|1||000395122||LEVERKUHN^ADRIAN^C||19880517180606|M|||6 66TH AVE NE^^WEIMAR^DL^98052||(157)983-3296|||S||12354768|87654321
NK1|1|TALLIS^THOMAS^C|GRANDFATHER|12914 SPEM ST^^ALIUM^IN^98052|(157)883-6176
NK1|2|WEBERN^ANTON|SON|12 STRASSE MUSIK^^VIENNA^AUS^11212|(123)456-7890
IN1|1|PRE2||LIFE PRUDENT BUYER|PO BOX 23523^WELLINGTON^ON^98111|||19601||||||||THOMAS^JAMES^M|F|||||||||||||||||||ZKA535529776
```

The above message is divided into four different types of segments: MSH, PID, NK1 and IN1.

**A segment** contains *fields* separated by the `|` *field separator*. *Field*s can be further separated by `^`, the so-called *component separator*, and contain sub-components denoted by the `&` symbol.

**MSH (Message Header)** tells the purpose of the message, e.g. its ID, seeding application, sending facility, receiving application, receiving facility, the type, date and time of the message, its HL7 version, etc...

**PID (Patient Identification)** holds information about the patient e.g. their ID, name, DOB, address, gender, race, admission date and time etc..

**NK1 (Next of Kin)** contains details of the person's closest relative/friend.

**IN1 (Insurance 1)** has details about the health insurance the patient has like Medicare, Medicaid, Tricare, etc. It contains the insurance plan ID, the name of the insurance company, the company's address, the name of the insured person, policy number etc...

Answer (score 3):

### Problem description

It is not likely that raw HL7 messages will be directly exposed to Google in the form of web pages as showing them does not make much sense for web users.

So in order to find your HL7 message samples you will have to dive little bit deeper underneath what web search tools show you...

### How to solve it

You should be able to find some message samples bundled with tools that work with them.

The tool developers needed some samples for testing their tools.

If the tool is open source, you should be able to find the message samples in the source code repository or get some samples by asking members of the development community.

In case of closed source tools it is likely that you will find some "demo" messages after installing the tool.

### Some solutions to get you started

Some tools that I find very useful that (may)contain HL7 message samples

- **(yes)** Inner Harbour Software's HL7Spy - http://hl7spy.ca/
- **(maybe)** Jeremy Reagan's Hl7 Analyst - https://hl7analyst.codeplex.com/
- **(maybe)** Mike Litherland's HL7 UTILITIES - http://nule.org/wp/?page_id=55
- **(maybe)** University Health Network's HAPI TestPanel - http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/
- ...

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, start from HL7 Version 2.7 standard specification itself, which you can download from HL7.org website. Once you've created an account there, go to Standards > Primary Standards > HL7 Version 2 Product Suite.
Some domains such as ADT are well covered, others have just a few samples.

If this is not enough, be a bit specific which particular message you are looking for.