# Are there any open data sources available for HL7 version 2?

Tags: hl7-v2

Are there any open data sources/servers or open APIs available for HL7 version 2?

I have found multiple open data sources for HL7 for FHIR
http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=Publicly_Available_FHIR_Servers_for_testing, but not version 2.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need sample message for HL7 V2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197778/need-sample-message-for-hl7-v2-7)